# Separating different parts of a list

Tags: arrays

I'm working with a pretty large list and I need to separate the list from `lst[7]` and up. How do I go about this? Here's the code / lists specifically (My apologies for not formatting the list in the code snippet way, this was a lot easier to read this way):

Comment: Search for python list slicing, which is the concept that allows you to do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your list, looks like everything you want will have `'year'` as part of it's first element.

So do this:

```
your_new_list = [l for l in lst if 'year' in l[0]]
```

`your_new_list` will be a list of list that only the list that you want.

This will filter for all the list in your list of list where the first element has `'year'` in the string.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i needed to do... apparently I forgot that slicing was a thing haha. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You just need the 7th elements and up from this list? I can't fully understand your last line. But if that's the case:

> lst2 = lst1[7:]

edit:
It actually looks like you want to skip the first nine lists, though, so it should be:

> lst2 = lst1[9:]